# How to call several command line arguments from a file in Bash?

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I have a compiled C++ **program which requires 2 command line arguments** to run - for example, if my arguments are "10" & "3000", "Program" would be run as `./Program 10 3000`

I want to **read the command line arguments from a file** called "args".

`./Program args` runs the program with 1 argument, `args`

`./Program "$(< args)"` where `args = "10 3000"` runs with 1 argument, `10 3000`

and lastly, `./Program "$(< args1)"` where `args = "10{newline}3000"` also runs with 1 argument, which is `10{newline}3000`.

**Is there any way to do this?**

For the record, the idea is to use something along the lines of

`./Program args1 < input1 > output1`, `./Program args2 < input2 > output2`, etc., so if there's any way to parametrize that as `./Program argsN < inputN > outputN` and just call `run(3)` or something, I'd be happy to hear it :)

**Note:** C++'s `cin` is not to be used for this, only `argc/argv`.

Comment: Did you try `./Program $(< args)` [without `"`] where `args` has `10 3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say this is your cpp program :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for(int i = 1; i < argc ; i++){
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is your input file :

```
10
30
Apples
```

Then you can do this :

```
./program $( < parameters.txt )
```

And the result would be :

```
 $ ./program $( < parameters.txt )
10
30
Apples
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: IT WAS THE QUOTATIONS AROUND $(<parameters.txt)
Thank you very much 